# How to get the getservbyname() C library call to work properly on Mac?

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the `getservbyname()` C library call, I'm using it like this:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  struct servent *sptr = getservbyname("tcp", "exonet");

  if (!sptr)
  {
    printf("No entry found for this service.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("service name is %s.\n"
         "service port is %d.\n"
         "protocol to use is %s.\n",
         sptr->s_name, sptr->s_port, sptr->s_proto);

  return 0;
}
```

The function aren't able to find the service entry, while it's available in the `/etc/services` file, and this function is supposed to get its entry from here.

the service `exonet` is available in `/etc/services` like so:

[image]

I tried also other services available in this file, but nothing is working, always I'm getting `No entry found for this service.`

I'm using gcc to compile the code on Mac OS Mojave.

What am I doing wrong and How to fix it?

Comment: Please post code as `formatted text`, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have accidentally interchanged the order of the arguments.   The manual page says:

```
struct servent *getservbyname(const char *name, const char *proto);
```

But you swapped the service name and proto in your code:

```
struct servent *sptr = getservbyname("tcp", "exonet");
```

Comment: that's actually right. I was doing the example I've found in some book, seems it's outdated.

Comment: More likely just a mistake in the example - the function appears to have originated in BSD 4.2 where it has the current order, and that seems to be the case in Linux and even Windows as well.

Comment: oh ok, may I ask where I can find these kind of information for later cases?

Comment: You probably know this but complete unix-ish systems have the `man` command, ie, in this case `man getservbyname` and that often lists some history.   A little web searching found an archive of BSD 4.2 man pages with was intelligible to this degree even without loading into a proper viewer.  And of course most of this is documented on web pages too.  Wikipedia also thinks BSD 4.2 was the first with TCP/IP but it's possible there were related capabilities with a different api in other early heritages.